# C#/WPF application suddenly can't insert data to DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm facing a strange problem with my application. I have a multithreaded application that is processing some documents and store some data in a SQL Server database.

After a log run (2-3 hours) I can see that the data is not stored into the database but all queries are running OK.

I also run this program in a single thread and still same problem. I'm using a connection pooling of C# with `SqlDataAdapter`.

Does someone have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Not a lot to be said on the data or code you've provided. What I would do is put some logging into the app, around the database inserts. Write e.g. the SQL you are going to run to a database table, and then write the result (or error message) to the table too. That way - if you can't attach a debugger to the process - you can see what might be happening.

Comment: i have log over these places, the strange thing is that i doesn't get any exception. logs says that all is good.